# c++ memcached_get doesn't return large values

Tags: c++, libmemcached

This program are working fine

```
memcached_st *memc;
memcached_return rc;
memcached_return error;
memc= memcached_create(NULL);
servers= memcached_server_list_append(servers, "localhost", 11211, &rc);
rc= memcached_server_push(memc, servers);
uint32_t flags;
size_t return_value_length;
const char *key = "52e0f1462379f";

char *response = (char*)malloc(10000);
response  = memcached_get(memc,key, strlen (key),&return_value_length,&flags,&error);

cout<< key<<":"<<response<<endl;
```

when there is a short value it returns something like that:

```
52e0f1462379f:x��VJ+S�R2$:{"fv":"11111111111111"}
```

But ,when the value length is bigger than 100 the result is:

```
52e0f1462379f:x��VJ+S�R2$:x��VJ+S�R2$
```

Does anyone know how to increase the max value length?